# Is there a way to extract the cost of a Google Cloud Function execution?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When we for instance deploy and call a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) with the PubSub trigger, we can receive the data and the context in Python as follows:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub.
    Args:
         event (dict):  The dictionary with data specific to this type of
         event. The `data` field contains the PubsubMessage message. The
         `attributes` field will contain custom attributes if there are any.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): The Cloud Functions event
         metadata. The `event_id` field contains the Pub/Sub message ID. The
         `timestamp` field contains the publish time.
    """
    import base64

    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))

    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
```

Is there a possibility to use the `context.event_id` or context to determine the total cost at the end of the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing for Cloud Functions is tied to the time spent for execution and the machine type you are using. This can be seen in [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#pricing_examples).

You would be better of checking with the Stackdriver logs for the time which the function took to execute, and use that as a basis for doing the billing approximation. I say approximation due to the fact that even with the logs timestamp, there may be a bit of discrepancy between your results and Google's billing at the end of the month.

Additionally, you would need to have an estimation of how many times you expect the function to be called in order to have a better appreciation of the total expenses to be expected for the month.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I will accept it as this seems the only solution right now, until someone perhaps has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can view this in the metrics explorer within the monitoring service on the google cloud console, which is a pretty accurate estimate. You can use the metrics explorer to construct a query that gives back the data you are looking for. An example of such a query is shown below:

[image]

Programatically you can get the same information using the monitoring API. Use [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query) page to construct and test the correct API call and call the API. You can input the query in the request body:

[image]